# How much can the President delegate to the VP or his staff?

Tags: united-states, president

To what extent can the President delegate the power of his office to his staff or the vice-president (VP)?  Could the VP effectively supervise cabinet-level staff?  What limitations exist?

Answer (score 3):

The President is free to delegate tasks as much as he would like.  There is no barrier to that.  However, the President cannot delegate Constitutional or statutory authority or the implied responsibility of the President.  That always resides with him.  For example, the President remains the Commander in Chief.

Comment: In other words, he can say "You handle this" to someone, but he's still responsible for whatever actions that person takes, and probably would be required to sign off on them.